# Custom setup on operating system and architecture

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have been asked to have a setup procedure running in  the following operating systems:
Windows Vista (only x86) and higher (both x86 and x64)

In order to restrict whole setup from running in older operating systems I added into `[Setup]` section the `Minversion=0,6.0.6000` that corresponds to Windows Vista.

I wonder if in Pascal scripting it is possible to apply a conditional installation like the following:

```
[Run]

Filename: "{tmp}\mysetup.exe"; Components: Install; MinVersion: 0,6.0.6000; Check: not Iswin64;

Filename: "{tmp}\mysetup.exe"; Components: Install; MinVersion: 0,6.1.7600;
```

This way mysetup.exe should run only on Vista x86 and on all higher operating systems.

Comment: Yes, there is just the [`MinVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams&anchor=MinVersion) parameter common for all sections using parameters.

Comment: You question is bit confusing. Your `[Run]` code does already what you ask for (run only on Vista x86 and on all higher operating systems). What do you need the Pascal scripting for?

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for your reply I was in doubt upon commands to be used. Meleena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GetWindowsVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversion) and [`IsWin64`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64) support functions:

```pascal
if ((GetWindowsVersion >= $06000000) {Vista} and (not IsWin64)) or
   (GetWindowsVersion >= $06010000) {7} then
begin
  // Install
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `MinVersion`
It's one of the optional parameters that are supported on all sections that support parameters.

Documentation can be found here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams&anchor=MinVersion